# Display Google Map markers with Mysql driven drop downs

Tags: mysql, ajax, google-maps, drop-down-menu

I have to populate values in a drop down from the MySQL data base, on selecting the value i have to generate google map with the relevant marker location on the map. Now my database structure and with values is as below

[DB with values](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/qlmgp)

i have a triple drop down logic, after i select the last drop down and click submit, i get the o/p as this " **You selected a Black Chevy Camaro** " as you can see the values that are selected are displayed so based on the values selected i have write a select query and in place of that text i need to display the google map with the marker using ajax.

the logic for triple drop down is here [triple drop down logic](http://pastebin.com/9Mn8pT9Z)